# How can I eliminate the empty line in code blocks rendered by jekyll?

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

GitHub Pages Jekyll use Pygments by default to render syntax highlighting for code blocks. But I prefer an easier alternative highlight.js to do the job because I only need to indent 4 spaces to mark code blocks in the markdown source files.

However, my R code are all mistakenly interpreted as php or perl or makefile or other type of code by highlight.js, and I want to manually mark the code block by

````
```r
(some r code)
```
````

instead. But when I use this, the first line of the code block always appears to be a blank line. I view the HTML source code produced by the 4-space mark, it is like

```
<pre><code>x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
lm(formula=y~x)
</code></pre>
```

which does not suffer from this problem.

How can I eliminate the blank line in the first line of the code block?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue today when I change my highlighter to [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).
With the help from others, I finally git rid of this blank line, and willing to share the solution. Basically, the `whitespace` inside `<pre>` is not trimmed, and be treated as a newline in the rendered page (you can use firebug extension of Firefox enabled with `show whitespace` to observe the extra line).

Then the solution is obvious.

1. put `pre` and `code` tags at the same line with your actual code. like this:

   ```
   <pre><code class="css">@font-face {
     font-family: Chunkfive; src: url('Chunkfive.otf');
   }
   ```

or using solution provided by [mhulse](https://github.com/mhulse) to make your raw post more readable

```
    <pre><code
    >line of code
    Here and ...
    Here
    </code></pre>
```

2. Write your own js code to trim L/R whitespace(s) of your content before it be put in `<pre>`

For more details, check this [page](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/191).